# how to get rootScope value from routeChangeSuccess angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get rootScope value in function from routeChangeSuccess in AngularJs as per following code. But I cannot convince why rootScope value is NULL when I output with console.log.

```
$rootScope.updateCurrentUser = function () {
    $rootScope.loggedUser = "1";
};

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    var path = $location.path();
    $rootScope.showIndex =
        path === LANG_PATH + '/';
    if ($rootScope.showIndex) {
        //undefined result found :(
        console.log('rootScope ' + $rootScope.loggedUser);
    }
});

$rootScope.updateCurrentUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell since your example doesn't show where the handler is attached and where the change to `$rootScope.loggedUser` is made, but if it's happening in a controller, you probably won't the event.

Controllers don't get created until after the event has been broadcast, and the controller of the current view will be destroyed before the next `$routeChangeSuccess` event is broadcast, which means you'll miss the event if you're deregistering handlers in your controller's `$destroy` event.

In the snippet below, you'll see the event being handled (and `$rootScope.eventLog` updating) in `.run` as you change routes, but not in the handlers in the controllers.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/main', {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/other', {
      templateUrl: 'other.html',
      controller: 'OtherCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise('/main');
}])

.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.eventLog = [];
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, curr, prev) {
    // we should see this, and $rootScope.eventLog will get updated
    $rootScope.eventLog.push({
      handler: "Run",
      event: e,
      curr: curr,
      prev: prev
    });
  });
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var deregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // this won't happen: we'll deregister before the event is called
    $rootScope.eventLog.push({
      handler: "Main",
      event: e,
      curr: curr,
      prev: prev
    });
  });
  
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregister();
  });
}])

.controller('OtherCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var deregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // this won't happen: we'll deregister before the event is called
    $rootScope.eventLog.push({
      handler: "Other",
      event: e,
      curr: curr,
      prev: prev
    });
  });
  
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregister();
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
    <p>This is the content of the main template</p>
    <a href="#/other">Other</a>
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="other.html">
    <p>This is the content of the other template</p>
    <a href="#/main">Main</a>
  </script>
  
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="e in eventLog track by $index">
      <h3>{{e.handler}}</h3>
      <pre>{{e | json:2}}</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```